# Download OpenOffice/Hunspell dictionaries (.oxt / .dic+.aff) for many languages at once?

Tags: nlp, language, global, corpora, dictionary

I would like dictionaries for the top ~100 languages or so.  Manually searching and evaluating the results at https://extensions.openoffice.org is quite cumbersome at that scale.

Is there a command line utility, .torrent or some other way to get dictionaries for all the major languages or for languages specified programmatically by locale?

Answer (score 1):

This site has the dictionaries.

https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries

Comment: Thank you.  But note that it does not cover the top 100 or so languages.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: It appears there are only [39](https://extensions.openoffice.org) at your link, so there might not even be a "top 100"?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/6b5bc65a32b534cf42159528e0232954) it lists 107 dictionaries in the python enchant library, but only 62 in the GitHub LibreOffice link. But they come from ASpell. 146 [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html).

Comment: I downloaded the hunspell and aspell dictionaries [here](https://github.com/wavebond/seed.chat/tree/make/import) for reference, got a lot more work to [convert them to JSON](https://github.com/GitbookIO/hunspell-spellchecker) and ditch the whole hunspell thing.

Comment: @Lance No, I did not.  The advent of multilingual models with Transformer-based architectures fundamentally changed how we approach these things.